# ezplatform url( ez_route not mapping to route of domain

Tags: php, symfony, ezpublish, ezplatform

I have a simple site, the base language is English with a translation of German.

Here is the site-access setup from the ezplatform.yml

```
# Siteaccess configuration, with one siteaccess per default
siteaccess:
    default_siteaccess: en
    list:
        - en
        - de
    groups:
        site_group:
            - en
            - de
    match:
        URIElement: 1

# System settings, grouped by siteaccess and/or siteaccess group
system:
    site_group:
        api_keys: { google_maps: "xxx" }
        cache_pool_name: '%cache_pool%'
        var_dir: var/site
        translation_siteaccesses: [de, en]
    de:
        languages: [ger-DE, eng-GB]
    en:
        languages: [eng-GB]
    default:
        content:
```

Works great, accessing `localhost:8000` displays english content, and `localhost:8000/de` displays german content.

I then built a simple language switcher:

```
<ul>
    <li>

        <a href="{{ url( ez_route( null, {"language": "ger-DE"} ) ) }}" {% if ezpublish.siteaccess.name == 'de' %}class="inactive"{% endif %}>
            Deutsche
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url( ez_route( null, {"language": "eng-GB"} ) ) }}" {% if ezpublish.siteaccess.name == 'en' %}class="inactive"{% endif %}>
            English
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But now i see there is a problem with duplicate content for SEO. When on the german site-access, the language switcher prints a link to the en site access for the eng-GB language as `localhost:8000/en` where it should be `localhost:8000`.

How can i tell ez to either redirect all /en content to /? I think there must be a better solution, but i don't see how in the docs :/

When i change how the matchers work to this:

```
siteaccess:
    default_siteaccess: en
    list:
        - en
        - de
    groups:
        site_group:
            - en
            - de
    match:
        Map\URI:
            /: en
            de: de
```

For the english translation i get a // in the url for english.

Comment: just a not-so-nice workaround;if you know eng-GB is going to stay your default siteaccess, why don't you simply define `<a href="/" {% if ezpublish.siteaccess.name == 'en' %}class="inactive"{% endif %}>Englisch</a> ` ?

Comment: Because this only routes to the home page. I need to switch language and land back on the same page eg '...com/somepage'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're using this matcher config and it works okay:

```
ezpublish:
    siteaccess:
        match:
            Compound\LogicalAnd:
                cro:
                    matchers:
                        Map\URI: { cro: true }
                        Map\Host: { '%site_domain%': true }
                    match: cro
            Map\Host:
                '%site_domain%': eng
```

Note that I'm using `%site_domain%` parameter which I defined myself in `app/config/parameters.yml`. You can do it too, or you can use a hardcoded value.

The downside is, you need to add all new siteaccesses to the list in `Compound\LogicalAnd` matcher, but if you have a simple site with couple of siteaccesses, it should be fine I guess.

Comment: Is there anything else i need to add to this? I altered your match from `cro` and `eng` to `en` and `de` but the result is a cache clear results in `Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "site_domain". in /mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/privatezimmer/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php:84`

Comment: Matching does work.. but not with the '%site_domain%' keyword. When i hard code the values it is fine, but otherwise not. There is myself and another working on this site and we both have different dev urls and of course another for production.

It seems the magic '%site_domain%' would be perfect otherwise i will have to hard-code a match for all the site accesses

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified that `%site_domain%` is a Symfony DIC parameter which I defined myself in `app/config/parameters.yml` :) I've updated the anwser to reflect that.

Comment: I added a pull request with a new guide, maybe you could take a look and see if it is not too far off the mark: https://github.com/ezsystems/developer-documentation/pull/27

Comment: Left a comment over there :)